# 401 error accessing codeigniter url with ajax from javascript

Tags: jquery, ajax, apache, codeigniter

I have a CodeIgniter application.  I'm doing something a bit squirrelly, accessing a controller from the javascript part of a view via ajax.

For those who aren't familiar with CodeIgniter, the controller and view are CodeIgniter constructs written in PHP.

The Ajax:

```
               $.ajax({
                   url: '<?php echo site_url('<controllerName>/<methodName>')?>',
                   type:'POST',
                   data: { parm1 : val1, 
                           parm2 : val2,
                           parm3 : val3 }, 
                   dataType: 'json',
                   success: function(output_string){
                   }
                 })
```

When I hit this code, I get an Authentication Required dialog asking for a user name and password.

The Firefox console shows the following error:

POST http://myurl.com// 401 Unauthorized

The associated response (per Firefox) is

401 Unauthorized

## Unauthorized

This server could not verify that you
     are authorized to access the document
     requested.  Either you supplied the wrong
     credentials (e.g., bad password), or your
     browser doesn't understand how to supply
     the credentials required.

---

Apache Server at myurl.com Port 80

Naturally, this problem doesn't arise when I run on localhost.  It only happens after we install on the client site.

I'm kind of at a loss as to where to look to find out what's wrong.

I suspect this is some kind of error with the server setup - but I am unsure how to confirm this.

Has anyone seen anything like this before?  How did you find the cause?

Comment: just curious, is this something that can be addressed via .htaccess?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22081684/ajax-call-needs-username-and-password for answer