# ajax call needs username and password

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm an Ajax newbie, so that might explain my question.

I'm doing the following call

```
                   $.ajax({
                   url: '<?php echo site_url('something/somethingelse')?>',
                   type:'POST',
                   username: 'username',
                   password: 'password',
                   data: { parm1 : 'A', 
                           parm2 : 1,
                           parm3 : 2 }, 
                   dataType: 'json',
                   success: function(output_string){
                   }
```

username and password are the username and password I use to sign into my server.

how can i represent them in the javascript securely?  i know i can store them in variables and use the variables in the Ajax call - but the variables will exist in a javascript file and be visible to anyone who can use a debugger that allows you to view the javascript.

is there a way to hide certain javascript files?  does javascript have the equivalent of a properties file?

Comment: You can't represent a password securely client side (Javascript). As for posting the data, the username and password should be part of the data array, but again, you can't do this securely with Javascript. You should use a good old HTML post form with SSL.

Comment: can you describe the HTML post form with SSL or include a link where i can read up on it?  is the requirement to include username/password with the Ajax call something that's controlled server side?  Could I get the folks who manage the server to turn it off?

Comment: its just a html form which happens to have an https url to post. you need an ssl certificate for your domain an ssl to be configured in your server for this to work though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

turns out this was a url conflict.

the ajax call was accessing a url, let's call it some.domain/stats

the hosting provider offers a free Statistics page that is password protected.  its url is also some.domain/stats

when my app accessed some.domain/stats, thru some weird routing I don't understand, I was directed to the password protected one.

when i changed the url the ajax call was accessing to something like some.domain/nameOtherThanStats then everything worked fine.

no htaccess changes needed.